# Definition of Prism Operator and homotopy of chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher.
For reference:
https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf
On page 112, in the first sentence of the last paragraph, we find the following:

> The terms with $i=j$ in the two sums cancel out, except for $F\circ (\sigma \times \mathbf{1})|[\hat{v_0},w_0,\dots, w_n]$...

It is not clear to why the pairs of terms in the series with $i=j$ should cancel out. In the picture of the decomposition of $\Delta^2\times I$ decomposed into $3$-simplices above, for instance, it is clear that the $2$ simplex $[v_0,v_1, w_2]$ is equal to both $[v_0,v_1, \hat{w}_1,w_2]$ and $[v_0,v_1,\hat{v}_2,w_2]$ but it is not clear that one is able to find any kind of nontrivial relationship between $[v_0,\hat{v}_1,w_1,v_2]$ and $[v_0,v_1,\hat{w}_1,v_2]$. This suggests that the correct cancellation is to pair up terms $i,j$ with $i=j+1$.

Is this simply a minor typo? Or am I missing something? I looked it up in the errata but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now what the wording is trying to convey; it escaped me at first. The message is that pairs $(i,j)$ in the first sum with $i=j$ match up and cancel with pairs $(i-1,j-1)$ in the second sum; that is, the pair $(i=2,j=2)$ in the first sum over $j\leq i$ matches up with the pair $(i=1,j=1)$ in the second sum over $i\leq j$. I will leave this up in case anyone else runs into similar confusion.